# Waking up Windows when in AwayMode

Tags: c++, winapi

I am using the Windows *AwayMode* to turn off the monitor and audio instead of going into sleep mode. This is working fine. How do I "wake up" the system when an event I want occurs? I can detect the event, but I don't know how to get the monitor back on and the system to appear awake again.

I have tried `GetCursorPos()` and `SetCursorPos()` to try move the cursor but that did not work.

I also tried the `CreateWaitableTimer()` and `SetWaitableTimer()` but that didn't work either.  I set the *fResume* option to TRUE.

I also tried to turn off *AwayMode* with the `PowerSetRequest()` handle and setting it `NULL`. That also did not work.

I also have tried the `SetThreadExecutionState()` call with no luck.  There is an *AwayMode* defined here as well.  I tried to set that and clear it, but the monitor doesn't come back on.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it using **SendInput()** with a mouse movement.  I also had to use the **SetThreadExecutionState()** to let the system know that a user is present otherwise it will go back to *AwayMode* in 2 seconds.  Here is the code I used.

```
// Get the current position to ensure we put it back at the end
POINT pt;
GetCursorPos(&pt);

// Make a mouse movement
// Go to upper left corner (0,0)
INPUT input;
input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
input.mi.mouseData = 0;
input.mi.dx = 0;
input.mi.dy = 0;
input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
Sleep(5); // Just in case this is needed

// Go to lower right corner (65535,65535)
input.mi.dx = 65535;
input.mi.dy = 65535;
input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
Sleep(5); // Just in case this is needed

// Restore to original
SetCursorPos(pt.x, pt.y);

// Now let the system know a user is present
DWORD state = SetThreadExecutionState(ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);
```